# Python 3D plot environment

Tags: python, 3d

How to interact with 3D objects (add, view, edit) like .obj/.stl files with in python

Answer (score 1):

You have the following python modules:

1. [VTK](https://pypi.org/project/vtk/)  is an open-source, cross-platform library that provides developers with an extensive suite of software tools for 3D computer graphics, image processing,and visualization.
2. [OpenMesh](https://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-6.3-Documentation/a00020.html) is a versatile halfedge-based data structure for representing and manipulating polygon meshes.
3. [Mosek](https://www.mosek.com/documentation/) this is more for optimizng the models